# Scheme: Changing the reader to accept i+j+k notation

Tags: vector, syntax, scheme, racket

Basically what I am trying to do with this is alter the reader so that it will accept vector notation like i+j+k. The goal of this is to convert things that look like vectors into strings while not affecting anything else. For instance, if someone typed in abc it would still throw an error message, but if someone typed in i+j+k would return "i+j+k".

This is what I have so far:

```
#lang racket/base 

(require syntax/strip-context)

(provide (except-out (all-from-out racket/base) 
                     #%top) 
         (rename-out (#%my-top #%top))) 

(require (for-syntax racket/base)) 

(define-syntax (#%my-top stx)
  (syntax-case stx () 
    [(_ . quat)
     #' (test (#%datum . quat))]
    [(_ . other)  
     (syntax/loc stx 
       (#%datum . other))])) 

(define (quat? testExp)
  (regexp-match-exact? #rx"([+-]?([0-9]+[i-k]?|[0-9]*[i-k])([+-]([0-9]+[i-k]?|[0-9]*[i-k]))*)" testExp))

(define (test x)
  (cond ((quat? (symbol->string x)) (symbol->string x))
        (else (strip-context x))))
```

This code does work in converting vector notation into strings. i+j+k successfully becomes "i+j+k". But the problem is that it converts EVERYTHING into syntax first, and I cannot get it back to whatever it originally was. For example, abc will become 'abc and it wont throw an error like it normally should. I have no idea how to get around this. I originally thought all I needed was a simple change to that else statement on the final line, but I cannot get anything to work. I am beginning to think I need to try a completely new approach. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, it should be noted that you have to have this code in one file, I called mine parse.rkt, and perform your tests in a separate file that only has

```
#lang racket

(require "parse.rkt")
```

Comment: Based on your previous questions and this one, I feel that you're really struggling with an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/13). It's best if you can talk about what your desired end result is, rather than trying to muddle through the steps that you "think" you should be taking but are instead just a big distraction.

Comment: That is, what is your overall project about, and what aspects of that project will your new proposed reader solve? (And don't say "so I can parse i+j+k"; that's not (or rather, had better not be) what your whole project is about!)

Comment: You may like to read this article: [On adding quaternions to Scheme](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/dorai/squat/squat.html). (Granted, that's just the top hit when I searched for "scheme quaternion"; you may find joy with other hits too.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scheme: Changing the definition of complex numbers to accept vectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21869745/scheme-changing-the-definition-of-complex-numbers-to-accept-vectors)